# What's the difference between generic pointer and void pointer?

Tags: c, pointers

What's the difference between generic pointer and `void` pointer?

```
void* gp;
```

Comment: "Generic pointer" is no formal term.

Comment: What is the difference between an automobile and a car?

Answer (score 8):

No difference. `void` pointer is itself called *generic pointer*.

Answer (score 0):

If you declare a pointer to void it's called Generic Pointer since you have to cast it to another kind of pointer first. Check the dictionary definition of generic. Both are the same, but this is just a 'description' of 'void pointer'.

This might seem useless but it has a very important use: you can use it multiple times to point at data of different types (int char etc..)